Remove rows with dplyr based on two conditions of two variables in R
I have a dataframe
day<-c(155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156,
       156, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157)
id<-c(149, 188, 206, 224, 151, 166, 186, 210, 226, 149, 188, 206, 224, 151, 166, 186, 210, 226, 149, 188,
      206, 224, 151, 166, 186, 210, 226)
var<-c(7.85481, 13.90381, 19.47181, 16.85981,  9.41781,  9.11281, 16.62381, 20.00081, 18.57781,  7.41781, 13.71681,
       20.21881, 17.73281,  7.29281,8.48781, 18.49481, 20.74881 ,19.13781 ,10.60381 ,17.51981 , 2.67881 ,18.29481, 10.60381 ,
       1.79581, 22.11081,  2.82081, 21.81281)
df<-data_frame(day,id,var)

df
> df
# A tibble: 27 × 3
     day    id   var
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   155   149  7.85
 2   155   188 13.9 
 3   155   206 19.5 
 4   155   224 16.9 
 5   155   151  9.42
 6   155   166  9.11
 7   155   186 16.6 
 8   155   210 20.0 
 9   155   226 18.6 
10   156   149  7.42
# ℹ 17 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

From which I need to remove rows based on two conditions:
I need to remove the day 157 of id 166, the day 157 of id 206 and the day 157 of id 210.
I tried the following:
    df%>%
    filter(!id==166 & !day==157,
              !id==206 & !day==157,
              !id==210 & !day==157)
    # A tibble: 12 × 3
         day    id   var
       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
     1   155   149  7.85
     2   155   188 13.9 
     3   155   224 16.9 
     4   155   151  9.42
     5   155   186 16.6 
     6   155   226 18.6 
     7   156   149  7.42
     8   156   188 13.7 
     9   156   224 17.7 
    10   156   151  7.29
    11   156   186 18.5 
    12   156   226 19.1 

> 

But that removes all rows of day 157
How can I combine both conditions?
Thanks in advance!

Option 1:
df %>%
  filter(!(id==166 & day==157),
         !(id==206 & day==157),
         !(id==210 & day==157)) 

Option 2:
'%!in%' <- Negate(`%in%`)
df %>% 
  filter( id %!in% c(166,206,210) | day != 157)


You could use anti_join instead:
df_remove <- data.frame(id = c(166,206,210), day = 157)
anti_join(df, df_remove, by = c("day", "id"))

#      day    id   var
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1   155   149  7.85
#  2   155   188 13.9 
#  3   155   206 19.5 
#  4   155   224 16.9 
#  5   155   151  9.42
#  6   155   166  9.11
#  7   155   186 16.6 
#  8   155   210 20.0 
#  9   155   226 18.6 
# 10   156   149  7.42
# ℹ 14 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


data_frame() has been deprecated since tibble 1.1.0. So use tibble() or
df<-data.frame(day,id,var)

And then this got me to your desired output
df %>%
  filter(!(id==166 & day==157) &
         !(id==206 & day==157) &
         !(id==210 & day==157))


This duplicates my answer.

@JilberUrbina had to make an edit

Splitting hairs, but this is a slightly different answer. This is one logical expression. Another option would be multiple arguments to filter()separated by commas, which are implicitly combined with AND. From the docs: If multiple expressions are included, they are combined with the & operator.

First, a way to make the tibble data_frame without the intermediate values
Second, I prefer the "Not Equal" filter function !=, and with that change in logic we switch from "and" & to "or" |.
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(day = c(155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 155, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157),
             id  = c(149, 188, 206, 224, 151, 166, 186, 210, 226, 149, 188, 206, 224, 151, 166, 186, 210, 226, 149, 188, 206, 224, 151, 166, 186, 210, 226),
             var = c(7.85481, 13.90381, 19.47181, 16.85981,  9.41781,  9.11281, 16.62381, 20.00081, 18.57781,  7.41781, 13.71681, 20.21881, 17.73281,  7.29281,8.48781, 18.49481, 20.74881 ,19.13781 ,10.60381 ,17.51981 , 2.67881 ,18.29481, 10.60381 , 1.79581, 22.11081,  2.82081, 21.81281))

df %>% filter(id != 166 | day != 157,
              id != 206 | day != 157,
              id != 210 | day != 157)

Similar R: Filtering by two columns using "is not equal" operator dplyr/subset
